# Removing unenecessry spaces after regex

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of strings like this:

```
t='Enter  FLAVIUS ,                         MURELLUS , a  CARPENTER , a
                         COBBLER , and certain other
                     COMMONERS  over the stage    !  '
```

i.e. strings with multiple spaces.
If apply the following regex, I manage to transform multiple spaces into one space only, which is what I want:

```
re.sub(' +',' ',t)
OUTPUT: 'Enter FLAVIUS , MURELLUS , a CARPENTER , a COBBLER , and certain other COMMONERS over the stage !'
```

I now need to get rid of the unnecessary space between a word a punctuation mark.

In other words, I would like the output to be:

```
OUTPUT: 'Enter FLAVIUS, MURELLUS, a CARPENTER, a COBBLER, and certain other COMMONERS over the stage!'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You might do a second transformation finding [`\s+(?=[!,])`](https://regex101.com/r/qRbxwX/1) and replace with an empty string.

Comment: \s+(?=\W) might work better to catch other non-word characters

Comment: so it would be something like re.sub("\W+(?=[.,?!'\";:-])","",x)?

Comment: what is the meaning of ?= in the brackets?

Comment: Actually \s works better because the \W would remove punctuaction duplicates like !!!

Comment: ?= is a lookahead, makes sure the string between brackets matches but doesn't make it part of the match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
t='Enter  FLAVIUS ,                         MURELLUS , a  CARPENTER , a                         COBBLER , and certain other                     COMMONERS  over the stage    !  '
print(re.sub('\s+(?=[!,])','',re.sub(' +',' ',t)))
```

output

```
Enter FLAVIUS, MURELLUS, a CARPENTER, a COBBLER, and certain other COMMONERS over the stage!
```